# Problema al mostrar lo que extrae con $_POST (Input)

Tags: php, entrada

Buenas tardes!!

Estoy haciendo un formulario de pedidos.

Este select, me saca el diseño de la familia BIFOCALES 
Decimos que guarde el ID del diseño, para que pueda ser enganchado después con la ID (Si o si tengo que trabajar con las ID)

```
 <select name="bif_oi" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>Seleccione diseño </opcion>
       <?php
              /* creamos la consulta */
              $result=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM disenyos where id_familia = 8;");

              /* utilizamos un ciclo repetitivo para obtener los datos de la tabla */            

              while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                  /* preguntamos si es el seleccionado por el usuario */
                  if (isset($_POST['bif_oi'])){

                  if($valores['id_disenyo']==$_POST['bif_oi']){
                  ?>

                  <!-- Llenamos el select con lo seleccionado por el usuario -->
                  <!-- Agrego el id del diseño como valor del campo -->
                  <option value="<?php echo $valores['id_disenyo'] ?>"selected> <?php echo $valores['nombre']; ?> </option>

                 <?php 
                   }

                  else {
                       ?>
                 <!-- Llenamos el select con los datos de la tabla -->
                 <!-- Agrego el id del diseño como valor del campo -->
                 <option value="<?php echo $valores['id_disenyo'] ?>"> <?php echo $valores['nombre']; ?> </option>   
                 <?php                    
                      } /* cierre del else $valores*/ 
                   } /* cierre del if del isset */

                  else {
                 ?>
                  <!-- Llenamos el select con los datos de la tabla -->
                  <!-- Agrego el id del diseño como valor del campo -->
                  <option value="<?php echo $valores['id_disenyo'] ?>"> <?php echo $valores['nombre']; ?> </option>   
                  <?php                    
                              } /* cierre del else del isset*/
                  } /* cierre del while */
                  ?>
      </select>
```

El problema, que al meter esto en el INPUT, No saca el nombre, saca el valor de la ID
 ¿Como puedo hacer que muestre el NOMBRE, Y no el ID

Dentro de este input:

```
<input type="text" name="lenteoi" value="<?php echo $_POST["bif_oi"]; ?>"/>
```

Agradecería mucho algún tipo de solución o propuesta.
Muchas gracias y un saludo! :)

Comment: explicanos que es lo que exactamente estas haciendo.

Comment: Es una tabla, para un vez terminado el pedido, mostrar un "Comprobar datos"

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que estas poniendo como valor del option, el ID

```
<option value="<?php echo $valores['id_disenyo'] ?>"selected> <?php echo $valores['nombre']; ?> </option>
```

Y eso despues se traduce a

```
<input type="text" name="lenteoi" value="<?php echo **$_POST["bif_oi"]**; ?>"/>
```

Para poner el nombre, y no el ID, tenes que poner el siguiente valor en option

```
<option value="<?php echo $valores['nombre'] ?>"selected> <?php echo $valores['nombre']; ?> </option>
```

Al margen, todos los option los estas poniendo como selected, y eso es un error... solo debe haber un option con selected.

Comment: El problema, que necesito que saque el ID, para en otro campo extraer ese ID, y condiciona otros desplegables. :/

Comment: Estas hablando de Dropdowns encadenados? Entonces necesitas que cuando seleccionas algo en ese menu, por un lago modifique otros dropdown que dependen de ese ID, y por otro, que cuando hagas submit no te de el ID sino el nombre. Es asi?

Comment: Correcto !!! Eso es exactamente lo que necesito, y por mucho darle vueltas, no encuentro una solución útil en ningún sitio, y tampoco consigo desarrollara yo mismo :/

Comment: Yo lo veo bastante simple.... Crea una funcion de onChange con JQuery, que llene un input hidden con el valor de "etiqueta". Por ej. 

Tu select tiene el ID target, el input hidden tiene el ID label...

$( "#target" ).change(function() {
   $('#label').val($(this+' option:selected').text());
})